# Angular condition to show spinner before subscribe Observable in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

im working Angular 15 project, i have a table where I want to show a loading spinner in a column before getting data from observable.

```
<tr *ngFor="let course of courseItems$ | async">
  <td>{{course.id}}</td>
  <td>{{course.name}}</td>
  <td>
    <ng-container *ngIf="condition to show only before getting data from course.additionalInfo$">
      Loading ...
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="(course.additionalInfo$ | async) as additionalInfo">
      {{additionalInfo.description}}
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

do you have any idea how can catch the moment before data subscription ?

Comment: I posted an answer already, but anyway... Could I see the controller code to visuallize `courseItems$` and how you call `course.additionalInfo$`. I am worried about how the Subjects are instantiated and you may need to seperately create Observables that pipes the Subject data to have working Loading Spinner. However if you use NgRx and Store you may need additional configurations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `*ngIf` conditional template rendering.

**Following code is not optimized. Use with CAUTION.**

```
<tr *ngFor="let course of courseItems$ | async">
  <td>{{course.id}}</td>
  <td>{{course.name}}</td>
  <td *ngIf="
       course.additionalInfo$ | async as additionalInfo;
       then courseInfoTemplate
       else loadingTemplate
  ">

    <ng-template #courseInfoTemplate>
      {{additionalInfo.description}}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #loadingTemplate>
      Loading ...
    </ng-template>
  </td>
</tr>
```

`*ngIf` directive can be used to switch between conditional templates.

Step-by-step

Syntax: `ngIf="condition; then trueTemplate else falseTemplate"` switching between trueTemplate and falseTemplate. | [Detailed Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else)

1. Angular converts course.additionalInfo$ to `Observable` that will live with current Template lifecycle.
2. `*ngIf` will load the corresponding template as content of the directive element.

---

### UPDATE 1 [Good practice] - Optimized `*ngFor` performance and readability / code maintainability

`<ng-template>` Elements defined into `*ngFor` loops may provide memory leak or performance issues and isn't recommended! <sup>*see note - |1|*</sup>

```
<tr *ngFor="let course of courseItems$ | async">
  <td *ngIf="
    course.additionalInfo$ | async as additionalInfo;
    then courseInfoTemplate
    else loadingTemplate
  ">
  </td>
</tr>

<ng-container>
    <ng-template #courseInfoTemplate let-additionalInfo>
      {{additionalInfo.description}}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #loadingTemplate>
      Loading ...
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

In short:
We have seperated the templates from the loop `*ngFor`.
We added `let-additionalInfo` attribute to the `<ng-template>` element. *ngIf will inject the resolved data as template variable (visible in the template scope). We named that variable: `additionalInfo`.

**Explanation for geeks:**

*Since we moved the `<ng-template>` elmeents out of the scope<sup>(context)</sup> we cannot access `additionalInfo` directly.
So we need to *decode* the 
 [Structural directive syntax (angular.io)](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-syntax-reference)
[image: Structural directive syntax]
<sup>*After 10 minutes of stairing* we begin to wonder whether we should seek an example from another 3rd-party source.</sup>
[image: Syntax explanation]*

`NgIf` may inject an context<sup>(data)</sup> to the if/else templateRefs.

| Rare Magic Artefacts | Hidden behavior or magic effects |
| --- | --- |
| `as` keyword | Define new named `local variable`. Example: `*ngIf="expressionToEvaluate as expResult"` will create local variable `expResult` visible within directive element scope. |
| `as` keyword with additional condition operators | `books$ | async as books && booksListEnabled then listTemplate else emptyTemplate` will create local variable `books`, but then `emptyTemplate` will be rendered. |
| `then` and `else` | [NgIf API docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#properties) `ngIfThen` / `ngIfElse` are `@Input()`s promerties of `NgIf` Directive. Regarding to the official API - They are `TemplateRef` and inject `NgIfContext` to the EmbeddedViews of the templates. `NgIfContext = expResult` (see row |1|) In most cases `NgIf` context is injected using `$implicit` - that means the data is will be injected queitly into the template. And ONLY if we announce we will use it with `let-` key definition. (see next row) |
| `<ng-template let-blah>`... | `let-` key define a local variable for the template. In this example `let-blah` will define `blah` local variable. `NgIf` will inject the books object into `blah` local variable. However Instead of using `books[0].title` we have to access it as `blah[0].title`. Note: Usually we want to stay sync and use `let-books` for the context. |

---

**Notes:** 
<sup>Note **|1|**: *Vary on different ng versions, angular compilator/cli versions or project configurations. Try to avoid this bad practice!*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The `async` returns null initially that why you can easily implement it with the following approach.

Please also checkout the new control flow in angular 17

```
<ng-container *ngIf="courseItems$ | async as data; else loading">
..
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
... your spinner
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I could pretend that `| async` would have `EMPTY` result only if the `Observable` didn't reply message at the moment of subscription. Various implementations using `BehaviorSubject().toObservable()` may emit a set of data immediately after the new `Observer` subscribes.

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that empty und null may different things in your view implementation. If the observable never emit the output stays null. 

If you want to handle loading with behaviour subject you need a technic to identify the loading either by using an additional variable or the null value inside of the stream.

Comment: See that you put the "loading template" outside the table: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8zhmz1?file=src%2Fmain.ts)